# Has the author ever indicated if there was to be a sequel to Freedom™?

Tags: sequel, freedom-tm

Has [Daniel Suarez](http://anobii.com/contributors/Daniel_Suarez/1128804/) ever indicated for there to a sequel to 's [Freedom™](http://anobii.com/books/Freedom/9780525951575/017da2fd0155182119/)? What open issues are left to solve or explore?

Comment: This question will provide mostly speculative answers, i think its a question you could discuss in chat.

Comment: Well, that's true, but someone may point at characters with unfinished business or future events and plans that were mentioned and never happened.

Comment: I hope so.  Great book(s).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it conflicts with our future works policy.

Comment: Voting to reopen because we do have information at https://www.reddit.com/r/dcdarknet/comments/6pxrbk/daniel_suarez_ama/

Comment: @J.PabloFernández: In case you didn't get a notice, Suarez provided an official answer on Reddit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think maybe a sequel could come from the aftermath of setting up the new society and maybe the resistance of the entrenched, old mentalities.  It could possibly carry on for years.

Also possible:

> Another possibility would be that a new protagonist could somehow find a back door into the system and start to manipulate it to his own means.

Yet another possibility is that this two books are just the first part of Sobel's plan...

There's lots of great potential in Suarez's universe.  Even a prequel describing Sobel's rise could be interesting.

Comment: Oh, the books as first part of the plan sounds like a great idea, although I'm not sure if this story within a story is really in style with Freedom and Daemon. By the way, you can mark spoilers with >! (or was it !>).

Comment: It's !>. Still getting used to that. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The author [has weighed in on this](https://www.reddit.com/r/dcdarknet/comments/6pxrbk/daniel_suarez_ama/) in a Reddit AMA on July 28th, 2017:

> I do plan on expanding the Daemon series, but I thought some time would need to go by for reality to catch up to the first two books. When Daemon was first published I got a lot of email along the lines of "the book is cool, but none of this will be possible for decades." I don't get those emails anymore.
>
> In the meantime, my publisher was kind enough to indulge my other interests (e.g. autonomous robotic weapons, information inequality, genetic editing, and more).
>
> The hiatus for Daemon, however, has given me plenty of time to ponder what might come next in that universe.

Answer (score -3):

> Well there could be something to the situation with Brian Gragg (Loki) and Heinrich Boerner the now rogue AI.